# how to proof if A × B ≠∅ then range(A × B)=B

Tags: set-theory

I don't know to proof if A×B≠∅ then ran(A × B)=B

I try proof but can't do.
ran(A × B)
I will get y∈B∃x∈A ,(x,y)∈(A × B)
I can't do next step.  Definition ran(A × B)={y∈B∣∃x∈A,(x,y)∈(A × B)}

Comment: I know $\mathrm{ran}f$ to mean the range/image of a function $f$. What is the ran of a set, though?

Comment: Yeah, no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1):

ran($A \times B$) is by definition contained in $B$. So you need to show that $B$ is contained in ran($A \times B$).

Well, let $y \in B$, and $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Notice that an $x$ does exist in $A$, since it is non-empty. Then by definition of $A \times B$ we have that $(x,y) \in A \times B$, so $y \in$ ran($A \times B$).

Comment: I'm not good at English. Thank you for answering my question even though I understand a little.